# Problems with starting process opendkim

Tags: ubuntu, process

I've installed package `OpenDKIM` in a ubuntu 14.04 server following the instructions [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Postfix/DKIM). But the process is not being started automatically. Then I tried to run the process manually:

```
sudo service opendkim start
```

which results in following error:

```
Starting OpenDKIM: opendkim: /etc/opendkim.conf: /etc/postfix/dkim.key can be read or written by other users opendkim.
```

**How can I start the process?**

Comment: Please refrain from cross-site posting.

Comment: That question on serverfault is more about signing, but this one is about the problem with running unix process.

Comment: You are trying to achieve the same goal, on SF _How can I run the process opendkim?_, here _How can I start the process?_ . Perhaps some clarification would make it better.

Comment: The error message is very clear.  You need to correct the permissions for `/etc/postfix/dkim.key`. A permission of `700` would be more restrictive and prevent that message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message indicates that the file containing the private key has insecure permissions.

Other users on the system may have read your private key. If there are other users on your system, then you need to change the key and consider anything that depends on the key to be compromised. If this is a server where only the administrators have an account, then there's probably no problem (there could be a problem if a remote vulnerability had allowed an attacked to read local files).

Make sure that `/etc/postfix` belongs to root and is not writable by non-root users. The same goes for `/` and `/etc`. That is, `ls -ld / /etc /etc/postfix` should show something like

```
drwxr-xr-x  25 root root  4096 Aug 30 05:59 /
drwxr-xr-x 148 root root 12288 Aug 28 09:45 /etc
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 Apr 11  2015 /etc/postfix
```

The numbers and dates may vary but the permissions and ownership must be correct. It's also ok, but not necessary, if the permissions on `/etc/postfix` are more restrictive or if it belongs to a different group (but it shouldn't belong to a different user). It's ok if there's a `.` after 
the permissions (that indicates the presence of an SELinux context).

Make sure that `/etc/postfix/dkim.key` is not publicly readable. It should be owned by the group `opendkim` or `root` and by the user `root` or by the user `opendkim`. It should only be readable by the user and perhaps by the group. Something like

```
-rw-r-----   1 root opendkim  42 Apr 31  2016 /etc/postfix/dkim.key
```

To fix the permissions on the existing file, run

```
chown root:opendkim /etc/postfix/dkim.key
chmod 640 /etc/postfix/dkim.key
```

I'm not familiar with OpenDKIM. These permissions are best for security (only root can change the configuration, but the service can read it), but it's possible that ownership by root doesn't work. If it doesn't, then run

```
chown opendkim:root /etc/postfix/dkim.key
chmod 600 /etc/postfix/dkim.key
```

Review your key creation procedures. You should not have ended up with a publicly readable key.